# Relation betweeen expected area of square and rectangle

Tags: probability, expected-value

Hello I am struggling with the following question, can anybody help please?

> Consider a positive real valued random variable $X$
>   Experiment A: Draw a sample of $X$ and create a square with it as the edge length, and call this square $S$. 
>   Experiment B: Draw two independent samples of $X$ and create a rectangle with these two as sides, and call this rectangle $R$. Let
>   $$A = E[\text{Area}(S)] (E - \text{Expectation})$$
>   and 
>   $$B = E[\text{Area}(R)]$$
>   What is relation between $A$ and $B$?
>   
>   **Edit**: I have no idea how to approach this kind of questions any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: As mentioned above, at least you should try to express those area in terms of $X, X_1, X_2$ etc.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by $E-Expectation?$

Comment: Hmm I found this question interesting it seems that the expected area of the square could be way bigger than the expected area of the rectangle if the variance of $X$ is super big...

Comment: @RiccardoCeccon I just meant that E(x) means Expectation of x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $A=E(X_1^2)$ and $B=E(X_1X_2)=E(X_1)E(X_2)=E^2(X_1)$

Comment: Ok so as E(X^2) >= E(X)^2 we can conclude A >= B. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: And the difference $A-B$ is actually the variance of $X$. Did you notice?

Comment: yeah from that observation I remembered this result of inequality!